# Is there a representation theoretic way to define the pullback of densities and differential forms?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

I find it convenient to define the bundle of densities of weight $\alpha$,say $\Omega_\alpha(M)$ over a smooth manifold $M$ as the associated vector bundle of the frame bundle $F(M)$ with the representation:
$$\rho: A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto |\det A|^\alpha \in GL(\mathbb{R}).$$

It would be nice to be able to define the pullback of these objects, without having to give an alternate definition of them as point wise homogenous maps from $\bigwedge^n T_xM \to \mathbb{R}$.

However, I am struggling to find a way to define the pullback of these objects via a map $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ that doesn't require that $\phi$ be a diffeomorphism.

The "natural" construction that comes to mind seems to need this in order to have a canonical bundle map between the pullback bundle $\phi^*\Omega_\alpha(N)$ and $\Omega_\alpha(M)$.

Is there any of going about this?